# How exactly will the US restoring sanction waivers on Iran's civilian nuclear activity help Iran?

Tags: united-states, iran

Recently it was announced that the Biden administration has restored the waivers on sanctions on Iran's civilian nuclear program - revoked in 2020 by the Trump administration -  which were part of the [2015 Iran Nuclear Deal](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-33521655). These waivers are restored as a goodwill gesture, but besides being a gesture, what does this mean for Iran? How will Iran actually benefit from these waivers in reality?

Comment: The reality is that lifting 1 or 10 sanctions have no effect, cause around 1733 sanctions have been imposed on Iran's vital sectors. you wanna know how Iran would respond to it? Iran says as long as all of the sanctions of Trump era and the sanctions that were supposed to be lifted by signing the JCPOA don't be lifted, and Iran doesn't verify that the sanctions lifting has been effective, no deal will be clinched, the west can't fool Iran by doing one or two hypocritical acts, even after the 2015 JCPOA no conspicuous effect has occurred on the Iranian economy, let alone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will change nothing. A lot of companies that were active in Iran in the past disbanded their commercial infrastructure given the pressure from the US. Dealing with Iran would require some preparation and some investments, but given how unpredictable is the US administration and how often things change on a whim those companies would not risk a long term commitment. Some firms might try some small deals, but the impact on the overall economy would be negligible. Things like a European or Japanese company selling equipment for a refinery or Airbus resuming the order for civilian aircraft made by the National airline are unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't address the crux of the problem which are crippling economic sanctions. However, it does allow other countries to go into Iran and help them achieve the JCPOA conditions at their nuclear facilities. It's basically an empty gesture to see if they can make iran comply by pretending to be nice

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ash-riveers, can you please present more details to your answer,

> "it does allow other countries to go into Iran and help them achieve the JCPOA conditions at their nuclear facilities."

In your statement please add what exactly the countries can contribute and in what manner